# Connecting REST WebService to MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, web-services

I want to create a REST WebService which is connected to a MySQL database. But I got stuck at a point and don´t really know how to get further.
This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using SimpleRESTServer.Models;
using MySql.Data;


namespace SimpleRESTServer
{
    public class PersonPersistance
    {

        private MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;

        public PersonPersistance()
        {
            string myConnectionString;
            myConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;uid=Local Instance MySQL80; pwd=;database=employeedb";
            try
            {
                conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
                conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
            {

            }

        }
        public long savePerson(Person personToSave)
        {
            String sqlString = " INSERT INTO tblpersonnel (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('"+ personToSave.FirstName + "','" + personToSave.LastName + "')";}
            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(sqlString, conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            long id = cmd.LastInsertedId;
            return id;
    }

}
```

So my problem is that in the savePerson function something doesn´t work. When I write 'sqlString' and 'conn' ind the MySqlCommand part, it always get underlined red. I don´t really know what´s wrong.
I listend to this guys tutorial: https://youtu.be/LpySuvYPMZQ
I hope somebody can help me.
Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: When I hover over 'sqlString' it says: the name 'sqlString' does not exist in the current context. When I do the same at 'conn' it says: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method or property 'PersonPersistance.conn'

Comment: In other to avoid that error, just remove the curly bracket at the end of sqlString in savePerson function.

Comment: add `static` to the conn declaration to fix the second issue.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are closing the method at the sqlString variable. Just after the semi colon you have a closing curly braces.